# How can I compare answer of current iteration with previous one in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

for example: computing f[f[f[x]]], I want to compare  answer of f[f[f[x]]] with the answer of f[f[x]].
I want to keep  iterating and comparing until answer of current iteration matches with answer of previous one. How Can I do that in Mathematica?

Basically I want to write Generic code for Fixed Point Iteration method for any function given by the user. How can I compare Iterations in this case?

Comment: Is there an other function that can solve my problem?

Comment: `TakeWhile[]` from a `NestList[]` is one option.

Comment: I have edited my question please review it.

Comment: Thank you for the help! However there was a mistake in my code I got that through your answer.

Comment: @Hizafa Take a look at [FixedPointList](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FixedPointList.html). You can specify a function to determine equality for stopping the nesting.